# OpenService function doesn't work in Windows 8 (advapi32.dll)

Tags: service, windows-8

I used OpenService function in a VB.NET project and it works without problem in Windows7 or Windows XP.

Something like that:

```
hService = OpenService(hSCM, sServiceName, ACCESS_TYPE.SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG Or ACCESS_TYPE.SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG)
```

The same function in Windows 8 doesn't work... It returns 0 and not the correct service handle.

What's happened in Windows 8? Have you any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does GetLastError () return?

Comment: I've tried and the problem was on user permission... and I solved running the application as administrator... Thank you.